# How to avoid KeyError when using a string value in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, header, dropbox

I am using the dropbox api to upload a file like this:

```
token = 'This is the token'
file_name = 'This is the file_name'
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\":\"/my/path/my-file-name\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}"
}
data = open("my-file-name", "rb").read()

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The problem is that the file name will change whenever I run this so I would need to do something like:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\":\"/my/path/{}\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}".format(file_name)
}
```

But when I do this I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "headertest.py", line 6, in <module>
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path":"/my/path/{}","mode":{".tag":"overwrite"}}'.format(file_name)
KeyError: '"path"'
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error, which version of python are you on?

Comment: I am using 3.7.3

Comment: You have nested `{}` inside your json string. You should create a plain `dict` first and put the file_name inside that. Then json.dumps() that into your header dict.

Comment: The problem is that Python doesn't know which `{}` is your variable to format, so it tries to format all of them. You can fix this by: 1. making a normal dict and dumping it 2. changing way you format your string - the easiest would be just adding strings - `"{\"path\":\"/my/path/"+file_name+"\",\"mode\":{\".tag\":\"overwrite\"}}"`

Comment: Hello @quamrana. Can you please elaborate a little. You can answer as well so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested `{}` inside your json string. You should create a plain `dict` first and put the `file_name` inside that. Then `json.dumps()` that into your header dict.

```
import json

token = 'abc'
file_name = 'This is the file_name'
arg_dict = {"path":"/my/path/{}".format(file_name),"mode":{"tag":"overwrite"}}
arg_s = json.dumps(arg_dict)

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Dropbox-API-Arg": arg_s
}

print(headers)
```

Output:

```
{'Authorization': 'Bearer abc', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path": "/my/path/This is the file_name", "mode": {"tag": "overwrite"}}'}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using *.format*, you will need to double the accolades that are supposed to be in the string, like this: {{ }}. Basically {{ is the equivalent of the slash to escape quotation marks, like this: \". Your code should look like this:

```
s = '{{\"path\":"/my/path/{}","mode":{{".tag":"overwrite"}}}}'.format(file_name)
```